# dequeue custom UICollectionViewCell but properties in cell are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use my custom UICollectionViewCell and use following code in cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
static NSString *newsCollectionCellFullIdentifier = @"NewsCollectionCellFull";
NewsCollectionCellFull *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:newsCollectionCellFullIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:newsCollectionCellFullIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.mainimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rss.png"];

return cell;
```

but after this line of code is executed

```
NewsCollectionCellFull *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:newsCollectionCellFullIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

"mainimage" property (UIImageView in my .xib file) is nil and I can't do anything with it. And my collection view shows nothing in it cells (but those cells are selectable and call didSelectCellAtIndexPath properly)

Did I do anything wrong? I use this way to dequeue cell from my other custom cell, It works normally but not with this one.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I added a picture from my debugging session. After dequeue... line of code is executed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfvTP.png

You see that imageView is nil.

AND dequeue.... method returns reusable cell even for the very first cell.

Comment: Have you register your custom cell class in `ViewDidLoad`? `

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: I have added a picture from my debugging session.

Comment: Registering the custom cell class actually causes this to break.  By registering the class, you overwrite Interface Builder's prototype cell and instead cause the cell to be created programatically rather than from your Storyboard.  Comment out the line where you register the class, and then you should be ok, or if not then you have a new issue that will lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a "NewsCollectionCellFull" designed in a storyboard/xib and that it contains a UIImageView. If so, make sure that:
1) the mainimage property is declared in code as an IBOutlet 
2) the UIImageView in the storyboard/xib is connected to that IBOutlet

Comment: Yeah, I have done that all. But turn out I solved the problem by loading nib file for UITableViewCell in initWithFrame method. Thank you for your help anyway. Appreciate it.